# Running Desktop UI Automation tests in Azure pipelines

Tags: azure, ui-automation, specflow, microsoft-ui-automation, flaui

I have UI Automation Tests written in SpecFlow & C# and automated using FlaUI. The tests are running absolutely fine on my local machine.
Lately, I wanted them to be the part of my UI Automation Build Pipeline.

Further to this, I had an Azure WVD as a secondary workspace so I went ahead and installed the `Interactive Agent` on it. The tests were running fine till the Time the `WVD` is logged in & its the current Active Window of my local machine. When I tried minimizing it and monitored the Agent, I started receiving errors mentioned below.

```
 "KeyBoard input not received"

    "Mouse Input not received"
```

I am using a lot of `Mouse.Click()` , `KeyBoard.Type()`& understand that because of minimizing the `WVD` things don't work

I want to ask our experts that what If I move the complete execution to a dedicated `VM on Azure` configured with an interactive UI agent and running 24*7? I would not like to login to the VM but expect that the tests should all run without any hindrance and the pipeline doesn't have above execution errors.

Comment: I used to run these tests locally using ```Visual Studio Test Explorer```

Comment: Trying installing a new private agent in your local machine, and run the pipeline with the newly installed agent, what's the result? Same error message?

Comment: No. It runs locally very well. I havent installed any agent actually on my Local. Do u want me to try that?

Comment: If you want to run them on VM, I would suggest one approach which works for me. You would need 2 VMs for this #1=> Where you actually run the test cases and #2=> Use this VM to open the #1 VM and once you trigger the test cases in VM #1 close VM #2 directly.

Comment: This is not a good solution

Comment: @Apoorv How did you fix it? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @parul Yes I managed in getting it done . I had to enable auto login into my wvd and the pipeline turns on the wvd, runs all the tests and shuts it down